# How could I manage permissions of jhipster's authorities?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, jhipster

I am coding a webapp using JHipster code generator.
I created 2 extra roles, now I have 5 in total:

```
ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_PRESIDENT, ROLE_VICE_PRESIDENT
```

I was wondering how could I manage their permissions to show some **RESTs**.

For example, I would like to let the **PRESIDENT** add new users to database, other simple users should not see the web service that do the work.

Is there a file that I'm ignoring by mistake that could help me with this feature?

Giving thanks in advice for your precious time,

Manuel

Comment: which version of JHipster are you using? AngularJS1 or angular 4?

Comment: AngularJS1, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new roles to JHipster needs to be added in 2 places.

The obvious one is the AngularJS frontend. To add your new role to user edit view, you add them to the select options in "user-management.controller.js" at `vm.authorities = ['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']`

To enforce the role at different places in UI, you either add your roles to the state JS files. Just add them to `data.authorities` (check user-management.state.js)

If you like to have a template block visible only if a user has the proper role, check out the `hasAnyAuthority` directive.

The other Part is to secure the backend. If using a current JHipster version and SQL database, authorities are stored in the database. Add your custom roles to `authorities.csv` of your liquibase migrations.

Last but not least, you can enforce roles in `WebSecurityConfiguration` or `MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration` (just look at the existing antMatchers)